# TensorFlow Object Detection API - Access Violation (Windows 10) - Nvidia RTX 2080 -- Fixed

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

i want to train my model using the TensorFlow Object Detection API. I used the following site as a guide: https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html

When i execute „model_main_tf2.py“, I receive following error message:

```
> 2021-12-25 08:48:55.333119: I
> tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow
> binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)
> to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical
> operations:  AVX AVX2 To enable them in other operations, rebuild
> TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags. 2021-12-25
> 08:48:56.460241: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device
> /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 5965 MB memory:  ->
> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0,
> compute capability: 7.5 INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy with
> devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0',) I1225
> 08:48:56.472224  6428 mirrored_strategy.py:376] Using MirroredStrategy
> with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0',)
> INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting train_steps: None I1225
> 08:48:56.472224  6428 config_util.py:552] Maybe overwriting
> train_steps: None INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting use_bfloat16:
> False I1225 08:48:56.472224  6428 config_util.py:552] Maybe
> overwriting use_bfloat16: False WARNING:tensorflow:From
> C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py:563:
> StrategyBase.experimental_distribute_datasets_from_function (from
> tensorflow.python.distribute.distribute_lib) is deprecated and will be
> removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: rename to
> distribute_datasets_from_function W1225 08:48:56.741702  6428
> deprecation.py:341] From
> C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py:563:
> StrategyBase.experimental_distribute_datasets_from_function (from
> tensorflow.python.distribute.distribute_lib) is deprecated and will be
> removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: rename to
> distribute_datasets_from_function INFO:tensorflow:Reading unweighted
> datasets:
> ['C:/Users/Ameise/Documents/tfAPI/workspace/training_demo/annotations/train.record']
> I1225 08:48:56.757323  6428 dataset_builder.py:163] Reading unweighted
> datasets:
> ['C:/Users/Ameise/Documents/tfAPI/workspace/training_demo/annotations/train.record']
> INFO:tensorflow:Reading record datasets for input file:
> ['C:/Users/Ameise/Documents/tfAPI/workspace/training_demo/annotations/train.record']
> I1225 08:48:56.757323  6428 dataset_builder.py:80] Reading record
> datasets for input file:
> ['C:/Users/Ameise/Documents/tfAPI/workspace/training_demo/annotations/train.record']
> INFO:tensorflow:Number of filenames to read: 1 I1225 08:48:56.757323 
> 6428 dataset_builder.py:81] Number of filenames to read: 1
> WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input
> file shards. W1225 08:48:56.757323  6428 dataset_builder.py:87]
> num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
> WARNING:tensorflow:From
> C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py:101:
> parallel_interleave (from
> tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated
> and will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating:
> Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length,
> num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is
> desired, use `tf.data.Options.deterministic`. W1225 08:48:56.772944 
> 6428 deprecation.py:341] From
> C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py:101:
> parallel_interleave (from
> tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated
> and will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating:
> Use `tf.data.Dataset.interleave(map_func, cycle_length, block_length,
> num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)` instead. If sloppy execution is
> desired, use `tf.data.Options.deterministic`. WARNING:tensorflow:From
> C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py:236:
> DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from
> tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be
> removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Use
> `tf.data.Dataset.map() W1225 08:48:56.804187  6428 deprecation.py:341]
> From
> C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py:236:
> DatasetV1.map_with_legacy_function (from
> tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be
> removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Use
> `tf.data.Dataset.map() WARNING:tensorflow:From
> C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:1096:
> sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated
> and will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating:
> Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense`
> instead. W1225 08:49:04.031615  6428 deprecation.py:341] From
> C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:1096:
> sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated
> and will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating:
> Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense`
> instead. WARNING:tensorflow:From
> C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:1096:
> sample_distorted_bounding_box (from
> tensorflow.python.ops.image_ops_impl) is deprecated and will be
> removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: `seed2` arg is
> deprecated.Use sample_distorted_bounding_box_v2 instead. W1225
> 08:49:07.271071  6428 deprecation.py:341] From
> C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:1096:
> sample_distorted_bounding_box (from
> tensorflow.python.ops.image_ops_impl) is deprecated and will be
> removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: `seed2` arg is
> deprecated.Use sample_distorted_bounding_box_v2 instead.
> WARNING:tensorflow:From
> C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py:465:
> to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will
> be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Use
> `tf.cast` instead. W1225 08:49:09.071966  6428 deprecation.py:341]
> From
> C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py:465:
> to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will
> be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Use
> `tf.cast` instead. Windows fatal exception: access violation
> 
> Windows fatal exception: access violation
> 
> Windows fatal exception: access violation
> 
> Thread 0x00002568 (most recent call first):   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py",
> line 576 in _handle_results   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\threading.py", line 910
> in run   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\threading.py", line 973
> in _bootstrap_inner   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\threading.py", line 930
> in _bootstrap
> 
> Thread 0x00001998 (most recent call first):   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py",
> line 528 in _handle_tasks   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\threading.py", line 910
> in run   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\threading.py", line 973
> in _bootstrap_inner   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\threading.py", line 930
> in _bootstrap
> 
> Thread 0x0000204c (most recent call first):   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py",
> line 816 in _exhaustive_wait   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py",
> line 884 in wait   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py",
> line 499 in _wait_for_updates   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py",
> line 519 in _handle_workers   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\threading.py", line 910
> in run   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\threading.py", line 973
> in _bootstrap_inner   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\threading.py", line 930
> in _bootstrap
> 
> Thread 0x000003b0 (most recent call first):   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py",
> line 114 in worker   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\threading.py", line 910
> in run   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\threading.py", line 973
> in _bootstrap_inner   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\threading.py", line 930
> in _bootstrap
> 
> Thread 0x0000191c (most recent call first):   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_dataset_ops.py",
> line 2839 in iterator_get_next   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py",
> line 783 in _next_internal   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py",
> line 853 in get_next   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\multi_device_iterator_ops.py",
> line 584 in get_next   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\input_lib.py",
> line 2021 in get_next_as_list   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\input_lib.py",
> line 772 in _get_next_no_partial_batch_handling   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\input_lib.py",
> line 740 in get_next   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\input_lib.py",
> line 683 in __next__   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\input_lib.py",
> line 679 in next   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py",
> line 160 in _ensure_model_is_built   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py",
> line 400 in load_fine_tune_checkpoint   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py",
> line 605 in train_loop   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\Documents\TensorFlowAPI\workspace\training_demo\model_main_tf2.py",
> line 105 in main   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py",
> line 251 in _run_main   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py",
> line 303 in run   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py",
> line 40 in run   File
> "C:\Users\Ameise\Documents\TensorFlowAPI\workspace\training_demo\model_main_tf2.py",
> line 114 in <module>
```

[application error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46VRy.jpg)

---

It only happens, when i train with the GPU. That means i have a problem with my Nvidia RTX 2080.
I tested my installation with the „model_builder_tf2_test.py“ from /models/research/. It completed successfully.
When I installed CUDA, i got this message after the installation:
Could the last two messages cause the problem?

not installed:

- nsight for visual studio 2019

  - reason: vs 2019 was not found
- nsight for visual studio 2017

  - reason: vs2017 was not found
- integrated graphics frame debugger and profiler

  - reason: see https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-vstools
- integrated cuda profilers

  - reason: see https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-vstools

pipeline.config:

```
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 1
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 640
        width: 640
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: "ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_keras"
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      min_depth: 16
      conv_hyperparams {
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00039999998989515007
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            mean: 0.0
            stddev: 0.029999999329447746
          }
        }
        activation: RELU_6
        batch_norm {
          decay: 0.996999979019165
          scale: true
          epsilon: 0.0010000000474974513
        }
      }
      override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams: true
      fpn {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
      }
    }
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
        use_matmul_gather: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      weight_shared_convolutional_box_predictor {
        conv_hyperparams {
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00039999998989515007
            }
          }
          initializer {
            random_normal_initializer {
              mean: 0.0
              stddev: 0.009999999776482582
            }
          }
          activation: RELU_6
          batch_norm {
            decay: 0.996999979019165
            scale: true
            epsilon: 0.0010000000474974513
          }
        }
        depth: 256
        num_layers_before_predictor: 4
        kernel_size: 3
        class_prediction_bias_init: -4.599999904632568
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      multiscale_anchor_generator {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        anchor_scale: 4.0
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        scales_per_octave: 2
      }
    }
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 9.99999993922529e-09
        iou_threshold: 0.6000000238418579
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
        use_static_shapes: false
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    loss {
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid_focal {
          gamma: 2.0
          alpha: 0.25
        }
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    encode_background_as_zeros: true
    normalize_loc_loss_by_codesize: true
    inplace_batchnorm_update: true
    freeze_batchnorm: false
  }
}
train_config {
  batch_size: 4
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_crop_image {
      min_object_covered: 0.0
      min_aspect_ratio: 0.75
      max_aspect_ratio: 3.0
      min_area: 0.75
      max_area: 1.0
      overlap_thresh: 0.0
    }
  }
  sync_replicas: true
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: 0.03999999910593033
          total_steps: 1000
          warmup_learning_rate: 0.013333000242710114
          warmup_steps: 200
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.8999999761581421
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "C:\\Users\\Ameise\\Documents\\TensorFlowAPI\\workspace\\training_demo\\pre-trained-models\\ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8\\checkpoint\\ckpt-0"
  num_steps: 1000
  startup_delay_steps: 0.0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
  use_bfloat16: false
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
}
train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "C:\\Users\\Ameise\\Documents\\TensorFlowAPI\\workspace\\training_demo\\annotations\\label_map.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "C:\\Users\\Ameise\\Documents\\TensorFlowAPI\\workspace\\training_demo\\annotations\\train.record"
  }
}
eval_config {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "C:\\Users\\Ameise\\Documents\\TensorFlowAPI\\workspace\\training_demo\\annotations\\label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "C:\\Users\\Ameise\\Documents\\TensorFlowAPI\\workspace\\training_demo\\annotations\\test.record"
  }
}
```

My versions:

- TensorFlow = 2.7.0
- Windows 10
- Python = 3.9.7
- Microsoft Build Tools 2015 Update 3 (14.0.25420.1)
- Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools (14.0.25420.1)
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x64) – 14.29.30135
- Google Protobuf Version = protoc-3.12.3-win64
- GPU = NVIDIA Corporation TU104 [GeForce RTX 2080]
- CUDA = 11.5.1 (cuda_11.5.1_496.13_windows)
- cuDNN = 8.3.1.22 (cudnn-windows-x86_64-8.3.1.22_cuda11.5-archive)

Nvidia-smi:
[nvidia_smi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9v7n.jpg)
nvcc –version:
[nvcc_version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMsYL.jpg)

Comment: "That means i have a problem with my Nvidia RTX 2080" -- that almost certainly isn't the case. The GPU won't and can't cause a host side access violation. That implies something in host code segfaulted

Comment: Hi, can you explain this in more detail? I understand that the GPU does not cause the access violation. But what do you mean by host code? the Pipeline.config?

Comment: Remove the edit and send it as an answer to this post.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I fixed the problem. It wasn't the GPU.

It was the Virtual Memory (Pagefile). I changed to "System managed size" Here is the link for setting the Virtual Memory: https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-manage-virtual-memory-pagefile-windows-10,36929.html